# attach .png file from server in email

Tags: php, email

I use this script to send emails: https://phppot.com/php/php-contact-form-with-google-recaptcha/

But I also want to attach a photo from the server

I tried to do that

```
    $toEmail = "member@testdomain.com";
$mailHeaders = "From: " . $user_name . "<" . $user_email . ">\r\n";
    $mailBody = "User Name: " . $user_name . "\n";
$mailBody .= "User Email: " . $user_email . "\n";
$mailBody .= "Phone: " . $user_phone . "\n";
$mailBody .= "Content: " . $content . "\n";
if (mail($toEmail, "Contact Mail", $mailBody, $mailHeaders, addAttachment('scripts/photo.png'))) {
    $output = json_encode(array('type'=>'message', 'text' => 'Hi '.$user_name .', thank you for the comments. We will get back to you shortly.'));
    die($output);
} else {
    $output = json_encode(array('type'=>'error', 'text' => 'Unable to send email, please contact'.SENDER_EMAIL));
    die($output);
}
```

does not work, how can I attach a photo in this script?

Comment: Have you tried using full path? `/var/www/.../photo.png` . I don't think that relative path would work. Not even a full URL `example.com/scripts/photo.png`...

Comment: What is `addAttachment` supposed to be? (And what would that return, that would make sense to pass to `mail()` as fifth parameter in the first place?)